# Laravel, Jenssegers & Cashier: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel, mongodb

When using Laravel with Jenssegers/MongoDB and Cashier, I receive the error:

Call to a member function prepare() on null.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to laravel/vendor/cashier/src/

Open both subscription.php and subscriptionItem.php and change

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

to

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the composer.lock and run this command

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

after that run these command as well:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

and restart your server. also, make sure you have installed the latest version of composer.

Answer (score 0):

use laravel [Overriding Default Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cashier-paddle#overriding-default-models) or [Using Custom Models options](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#using-custom-models)

paddle: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cashier-paddle#overriding-default-models

Stripe: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#using-custom-models

to override cashier models with your models (extend these models with Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model)